# Elastic Beanstalk: How to write files to a folder in my node.js project folder

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an application on my local machine(mac os x) that generates a report and saves it to a folder in my web project folder.  When I deploy the app., this folder should get published as well. Granted, no one should have access to this folder but the app.  When I run the code to generate the report works fine on my local machine, but it seems to hang on elastic beanstalk.  What do I need to do to make this work on the elastic beanstalk environment?

In a nutshell, I am using phantomjs to convert a dynamic webpage into a pdf file that gets emailed to the appropriate parties involved.  Here is the code that generates the file:

```
page.viewportSize = { width: 2000, height: 800 };
//page.paperSize = { format: 'Letter', orientation: 'landscape', margin: '1cm' };
page.paperSize = { width: '1280px', height: '800px', margin: '0px' };
page.settings.localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled = true;
page.settings.loadImages = true;
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;


page.open("http://example.com/report/" + args[1], function start(status) {
  if (status === 'fail'){
      phantom.exit(1);
      return;
  }

//page.render('/dev/stdout', { format: 'pdf' });
  page.render(fs.workingDirectory + '/tmp/' + args[3], { format: 'pdf' });
  phantom.exit();
  return;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directory to which your ElasticBeanstalk application is deployed should be considered read-only after the deployment is complete. If you need to write files at run time, you should use a writeable directory such as `/tmp`.

Comment: Where can I add this folder to make it writable?

Comment: Will I have to remote desktop into the machine to do this?

Comment: If your EB server is running linux, then `/tmp` should automatically be available and world-writeable by default. However, it would probably make more sense to use a Node method like `os.tmpdir()` rather than hardcoding the directory name.

Comment: Would the node application have access to this folder or would I have to set any permissions?

Comment: All applications should have read and write access to the temp directory by default.